# Having Problem in Creating slugs for Japanese language using LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, slug

I am creating this app using laravel. It requires to have Japanese slugs because almost all of the content is in Japanese language. I tried to use several packages but none of them provide good support to Japanese language. So, I am trying to create it myself. In order to have proper slug I am trying to achieve these..

1. strips HTML & PHP
2. strips special chars
3. converts all characters to lowercaps
4. replaces whitespaces, underscores and periods by hyphens/dashes
5. reduces multiple consecutive dashes to one

To strips special characters I thought of using **preg_replace()** but the problem is it is also removing the Japanese letters. I tried encoding it to utf8 but no solution. Now, I want to create the function that will replace all the characters not required in a slug.

```
$slug = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", utf8_encode(strtolower((str_replace(' ', '-', $title)))));
```

So, I want a list/array of characters that must be replaced. I have listed these.If you think any other characters must be considered please help?

```
array("~", "!", "@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+","}","{","[","]",".",",","\\","/","|");
```

If you have any alternative solution to this I would love to use that.

Comment: if i remember correctly, UTF-8 doesnt support japanese fully... you have to use UNICODE

Comment: do not use normal `str*` functions on multi-byte strings because these only work on ASCII strings and will probably break multi-byte strings. Use the [`mb_*` equivalents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php). Also do not use `utf8_encode` because generally speaking it will not work unless you already have `ISO-8859-1` as the input string which is highly unlikely if you have Japanese characters

Comment: @apokryfos will definitely consider that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a string helper to convert a string to ASCII which might help. It is also baked in the `slug` helper. Try this:

```
Str::slug($title, '-', 'ja');
```

Comment: Thank you, It did work but as you said it converts a string to ASCII. For the title  =>サービス登録 サービス登録  ... it gives "sabisudeng-lu-sabisudeng-lu" but for SEO purpose we would want it to be "サービス登露-サービス登露" . So I think creating the custom function is the best option.